# Calling showOpenFilePicker : how avoid "must come from gesture" when calling class methods

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, local-files

Accessing the local filesystem a la: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileHandle

If I inline all my code for the show(Open|Save)FilePicker API logic directly in my button event closure or call plain fn's then things work ok. However, if I define a class w/helper methods and call those from my event-handler, and those helpers call the file pickers, then I get this error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'showOpenFilePicker' on 'Window': Must be handling a user gesture to show a file picker.`

I assume the the security system is looking at `this` to establish the gesture context - is there a way to re-establish this context with code running in my class?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the class methods were a red herring -- the issue has to do with async code and promises -- this is what looses the context and causes the error.
You need to make any calls to the FS without any promise chaining.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007274/what-is-must-be-handling-a-user-gesture-to-show-a-permission-request-errror-m

just put a button and put function in onclick()... :)