# What is "Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request." errror message in Chrome Web Serial API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, serial-port, modbus

I am a real beginner when it comes to programming. It is my intention to control a device with the API integrated in Google Chrome via the COM port RS485. I try to reproduce the following tutorial: https://web.dev/serial/

The following error message appears in the console:

"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'requestPort' on 'Serial': Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request."

How can I fix this error?

Thank you very much for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>examplepage</title>
    <script>
    async function caller() {
        // Prompt user to select any serial port.
    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();

    // Wait for the serial port to open.
    await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
    };
    
    if ("serial" in navigator) {
  alert("Your browser supports Web Serial API!");
  caller();
}
    else {alert("Your browser does not support Web Serial API, the latest version of Google Chrome is recommended!");};
    
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message `"Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request."` means `navigator.serial.requestPort()` must be called inside a function that responds to a user gesture such as a click.

In your case, it would be something like below.

```html
<button>Request Serial Port</button>
<script>
  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', async function() {

    // Prompt user to select any serial port.
    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();

    // Wait for the serial port to open.
    await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. I hope it helps others who are interested.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>examplepage</title>
    <script>
    async function start() 
    {
            // Prompt user to select any serial port.
            const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();

            // Wait for the serial port to open.
            await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
    }
    
    if ("serial" in navigator) {
  alert("Your browser supports Web Serial API!");
}
    else {alert("Your browser does not support Web Serial API, the latest version of Google Chrome is recommended!");};
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <button onclick="start()">Click me</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```