# handling a user gesture to show a file picker react issue

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code. Its downloading file from the server. After file data load I need to save it using showSaveFilepicker. So I tried to do this like below.

```
    useEffect(() => {
  const getDatas = async () => {
    if (downloadData) {
      debugger;
      if(clickedCheckout === true)
      {  
        const options = {
          types: [{
            description: 'Text file',
            accept: {'application/msword': ['.docx']},
          }],
        };
 
        const handle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(options);
       await writeFile(handle, downloadData) 
        return handle;
      }
    }
  }
  getDatas()
});
```

But I am getting this error. Also I have no idea to pass my blob data to this.

**Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Failed to execute 'showSaveFilePicker' on 'Window': Must be handling a user gesture to show a file picker.**

I can't add this directly to the button click. After button click my document data loading. that's why i have added it inside useeffect.

Button click event code.

```
 {
    key: "CheckOut",
    text: _setCheckoutText(item),
    onClick: async () => {
      await onCheckoutDocuments(item.class,item.sheetNo,item.fileNo,item.title);  
    },
  }
```

Please give suggestions to fix this.

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017650/16550663

Comment: can u show your button click handler?

Comment: i will update it in the question

Comment: @irous pls check now

Comment: sorry but it's really hard to help if you just show discrete code like this. please show your code as real and readable as possible so that me or someone else can come up with a solution for you.

Comment: Code is very big so i have shorted it.