# Electron serial port wants user gesture

Tags: electron, serial-port

I am getting the following error in Electron application, I want my application to connect to a serial port without any movement of the users:

main.dbaf3ab0354240df.js:1 Requesting port error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'requestPort' on 'Serial': Must be handling a user gesture to show a permission request.

Here is my code:

```
function onReady() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    frame: false,
    kiosk: true,
    isTrusted: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }

  });

  
  win.webContents.session.on('select-serial-port', (event, portList, webContents, callback) => {
    // Add listeners to handle ports being added or removed before the callback for `select-serial-port`
    // is called.
   win.webContents.session.on('serial-port-added', (event, port) => {
      console.log('serial-port-added FIRED WITH', port)
      // Optionally update portList to add the new port
    })

   win.webContents.session.on('serial-port-removed', (event, port) => {
      console.log('serial-port-removed FIRED WITH', port)
      // Optionally update portList to remove the port
    })

    event.preventDefault()
    if (portList && portList.length > 0) {

      setTimeout(() => { // Introduce a delay
      if (portList[11]) { // Ensure port exists at index 11
        callback(portList[11].portId);
        win.webContents.send('serial-port-selected', portList[11].portId);
      } else {
        // Handle scenario where port doesn't exist 
        console.error("Port not found at index 11");
        callback(''); // Or handle the error differently
      }
    }, 500); // Adjust delay as needed
      // if(portList[11].portId!=undefined)
      // callback(portList[11].portId)
      // console.log('callback called with', portList)
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line n/no-callback-literal
      callback('') // Could not find any matching devices
      //console.log('callback called with empty string')
    }
  })

 win.webContents.session.setPermissionCheckHandler((webContents, permission, requestingOrigin, details) => {
    if (permission === 'serial' && details.securityOrigin === 'file:///') {
      return true
    }

    return false
  })

 win.webContents.session.setDevicePermissionHandler((details) => {
    if (details.deviceType === 'serial' && details.origin === 'file://') {
      return true
    }

    return false
  })

  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(
      __dirname,
      'dist/frontend/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
  }));


  //win.loadURL('http://localhost:42001/oled');
  

}

  
  
  
app.on('ready', onReady);
```

Any suggestion on how to handle this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007274/what-is-must-be-handling-a-user-gesture-to-show-a-permission-request-errror-m

Comment: Unfortunately in this solution, the user has to click on a button :/

Comment: Yes, that's what "must be handling a user gesture" means.