# Pass dropdown menu selection to Pyodide

Tags: javascript, python, html-select, webassembly, pyodide

I am trying to pass the value selected by the user from the dropdown menu to the Python code in Pyodide. In the simplified example below, I am trying to:

- Read the user-selected input file
- Convert file contents to lowercase
- Append the user-selected value of "strand" (for example, the string "negative")
- Write the results to file 'out.txt' that can be downloaded by the user

For the input file with contents `Hello World!`, I expect that the output file to have:

```
hello world!
negative
```

Instead, I got:

```
hello world!
[object HTMLSelectElement]
```

Full page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.22.1/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Input file:
    <button>Select file</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Strand:
    <select id="strand" class="form-control sprites-arrow-down" name="strand" value>
      <option id="val" value="positive" selected>positive</option>
      <option id="val" value="negative">negative</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function main() {
          // Get the file contents into JS
          const [fileHandle] = await showOpenFilePicker();
          const fileData = await fileHandle.getFile();
          const contents = await fileData.text();
          
          var d = document;
          d.g = d.getElementById;
          var strand = d.g("strand");
          
          // Create the Python convert toy function
          let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
          let convert = pyodide.runPython(`
from pyodide.ffi import to_js
def convert(contents, strand):
    return to_js(contents.lower() + str(strand))
convert
      `);

          let result = convert(contents, strand);
          console.log(result);
          
          const blob = new Blob([result], {type : 'application/text'});
          
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          
          var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
          downloadLink.href = url;
          downloadLink.text = "Download output";
          downloadLink.download = "out.txt";
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          
      }
      const button = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', main);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code is based on this post: [Select and read a file from user's filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75806497/967621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the method shown in the answer here: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/967621) to access the selected value and pass it to Pyodide.

Here is how to get the selected value, such as `negative`:

```
var e = document.getElementById("strand");
var strand = e.value;
```

And the complete page code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.22.1/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Input file:
    <button>Select file</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    Strand:
    <select id="strand" class="form-control sprites-arrow-down" name="strand" value>
      <option value="positive" selected>positive</option>
      <option value="negative">negative</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function main() {
          // Get the file contents into JS
          const [fileHandle] = await showOpenFilePicker();
          const fileData = await fileHandle.getFile();
          const contents = await fileData.text();

          var e = document.getElementById("strand");
          var strand = e.value;
                    
          // Create the Python convert toy function
          let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
          let convert = pyodide.runPython(`
from pyodide.ffi import to_js
def convert(contents, strand):
    return to_js(contents.lower() + strand)
convert
      `);

          let result = convert(contents, strand);
          console.log(result);
          
          const blob = new Blob([result], {type : 'application/text'});
          
          let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          
          var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
          downloadLink.href = url;
          downloadLink.text = "Download output";
          downloadLink.download = "out.txt";
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          
      }
      const button = document.querySelector('button');
      button.addEventListener('click', main);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```